# How to setup Zuul settings

Tags: spring, netflix-zuul

I have a problem, I think it's about Zuul's rescues. I searched the internet but found nothing to fix this error.
I have a login in the project, but first I have to create a user and when I do this I get this error. When creating a user, I just send the nickname and password in the form of JSON. After sending JSON, the user is not saved to db.
**its logs form zuul**

```
WARN 11880 --- [io-4200-exec-10] c.n.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper  : Content-length different from byte array length! cl=56, array=0
2020-09-16 17:57:28.914  WARN 11880 --- [io-4200-exec-10] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: 
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.findZuulException(SendErrorFilter.java:118) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.run(SendErrorFilter.java:78) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.error(FilterProcessor.java:105) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.error(ZuulRunner.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.error(ZuulServlet.java:145) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
```

**bootstrap.yml form gateway**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-server
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: false
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      fail-fast: true
      retry:
        max-attempts: 20
server:
  port: 4200
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    credit-service:
      path: /credit/**
      serviceId: credit-service
    auth-service:
      path: /auth/**
      serviceId: auth-service
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 80000
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 20000
  ConnectTimeout: 20000
```

**and this is log from auth-service when I create user**

```
WARN 11216 --- [o-auto-1-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket]
```

**Edit**

```
IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:129) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:129) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.sendError(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:488) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
```

**I solved the problem. I had to improve JwtAuthorizationFilter**

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Looks like you're not sending data with your request. Have you tried sending it directly to your service?

Comment: @George I have tried and everything works fine. Now I am getting another error. If you can check it